# Lightbox sometimes doesn't go away when popup is closed in user profile editor

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface

If in profile I will enter something that will cause an error during saving profile:

> [image]

and click "customize your profile just on this community."

> [image]

and then click "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities"

> [image]

and then click "save changes everywhere"

> [image]

It will show a error, but background will still be darkened despite of disappearing of alert.

[image]

It, however, will be lightened again if I click somewhere within the bounds of window.

Comment: The entire warning popup seems to have since been removed, so this issue does not appear to be reproducible any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is in the code that loads the warning popup, found in the HTML source of the profile editing page:

```js
form.loadPopup({
    html: html,
    lightbox: true,
    loaded: function($popup) {
        $popup.find('.popup-actions-submit').click(function(e) {
            StackExchange.helpers.closePopups('.popup');
            form.submit();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $popup.find('.popup-actions-close').click(function(e) {
            StackExchange.helpers.closePopups('.popup');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

The call to `StackExchange.helpers.closePopups('.popup')` removes the popup itself, but not the "lightbox" covering the page.

For the close button, that doesn't matter, since the `loadPopup()` method attaches its own built-in event handler that does it automatically.  (In fact, the whole close button event handler above appears to be redundant.)  However, there's no such automatic event handler for the submit button, so the lightbox remain until it's dismissed some other way (e.g. by clicking it, or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Simply adding the line:

```js
$('#lightbox').fadeOutAndRemove();
```

at some appropriate location (e.g. in the submit button click event handler, or in the error handling code for the form submission itself) ought to fix this.

Comment: Now all we need is a dev to fix it and tag it as completed :)